# P/Invoke call to CreateEnvironmentBlock taking up to 30 seconds?

Tags: c#, performance, winapi, pinvoke

I've been using the `ProcessStarter` C# class from [this CodeProject page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36581/Interaction-between-services-and-applications-at-u) to start a process as the interactive user from within a Windows service.

I've noticed (after testing the code on ~50 different computers, running both Win7 and XP) that the P/Invoke call to [`CreateEnvironmentBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762270%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (in the `Run` method) can take up to 30 seconds to return (sometimes it's fast, other times not).

I saw that [someone else had this problem, but they were getting an error](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/c6512846-adb5-4235-8a02-1e4b5536e347/) (for me it always works).

**Why can calls to [`CreateEnvironmentBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762270%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) take so long?**

---

P/Invoke declaration:

```cs
[DllImport("userenv.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool CreateEnvironmentBlock(out IntPtr lpEnvironment, IntPtr hToken, bool bInherit);
```

`CreateEnvironmentBlock` call:

```cs
IntPtr lpEnvironment = IntPtr.Zero;
bool resultEnv = CreateEnvironmentBlock(out lpEnvironment, primaryToken, false);
```

---

EDIT: Additional information:

- It is not *always* 30 seconds - it varies (across different computers) between a few seconds to 30 seconds.
- [`procmon`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) shows a whole bunch of registry reads to such keys as `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` and `HKCU\Volatile Environment`, but ***no network activity***.
- Access to the domain controller on a domain workstation appears to make no difference to the length of the call.
- `perfmon` shows little to no CPU usage, and only an initial and end I/O spike:

  [image: perfmon graph]

  The `CreateEnvironmentBlock` call in this example took approximately 12 seconds.
- [The MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762270%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) infers that calls to `CreateEnvironmentBlock` do *not* load the user's profile (and the user is already logged in anyway, so their profile must be loaded):

  > User-specific environment variables such as %USERPROFILE% are set only when the user's profile is loaded. To load a user's profile, call the LoadUserProfile function.

Comment: That 30 seconds sounds an awful lot like a network time out. Can you use procmon (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see what's going on at the start of that waiting period?

Comment: @Gabe: procmon shows a whole bunch of registry reads to `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`, `HKCU\Volatile Environment`, etc. to retrieve environment variables, but no network activity at all. Tested that on a domain computer with a domain account logged-in, without network access to the domain controller.

Comment: Also, it's not always 30 seconds. It can be anywhere between 5 and 30 seconds, which would make sense if it's due purely to the registry reads (since some computers/users have more environment variables than others), but surely registry reads alone wouldn't take that long?

Comment: Is there CPU or disk usage during that time? If so, it could indicate that the registry reads are the culprit (although your computer should be able to do millions of registry reads in that amount of time). Also, does having access to the DC affect the duration of the call?

Comment: @Gabe: DC access does not appear to have any affect on the duration of the call. I checked CPU and I/O using perfmon, and it showed an initial spike in I/O then nothing for the rest of the time (and no visible CPU time). ([Here's the graph from perfmon](http://i.imgur.com/F9hyw.png) - the last spike is where `CreateEnvironmentBlock` finished, taking ~12 seconds)

Comment: @Xenon - I'm absolutely certain that Gabe is correct, and the issue is network traffic.  Somebody's phoning home to A/D, or trying to read some share, or gosh knows what.  But it's almost certainly network.  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4: That would make sense, but no network traffic is being shown by `procmon`, which is bewildering...

Comment: @Xenon: Procmon may be associating the network traffic with another process which is trusted to enforce security and doing the actual lookup.  Probably csrss or lsass.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yeah, I've been thinking that might be the case. I'll investigate further.

Comment: Quick update on this: I've just done a test on a non-domain workstation and the `CreateEnvironmentBlock` call was practically instant. The test computer did have an SSD, though, but it's looking very likely to be something related to AD lookups, as many of you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Because Creating the environment block for a different user requires loading the profile for that user. If you're on a domain controlled machine this will be doubly slow because it requires talking with and downloading the profile from your Active Directory machine on the network.

Comment: No, this answer is not correct. `CreateEnvironmentBlock` retrieves environment variables for an already-logged-in user, who's profile is already loaded. This is why a user token is passed to `CreateEnvironmentBlock`.

Comment: @Xenon: The existence of a logon token does NOT mean that the user's profile is already loaded.  Notice that `LoadUserProfile` also accepts the token as a parameter.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Oh, indeed. The MSDN documentation for `CreateEnvironmentBlock` does infer that it won't load the user profile, however. When I call `CreateEnvironmentBlock`, I'm passing the token for a user logged into an interactive session, so their profile _should_ already be loaded, right?

Comment: @Xenon: In that case, I would say yes, the profile should have been loaded already as part of the interactive login process.